# Why I am getting UnreachableBrowserException while executing my selenium test in Cucumber but in simple maven project it is working fine?

Tags: java, selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

In Cucumber project I have used Selenium 4.0 aplha and in Simple maven project I have used Selenium 3.14
Is that the reason. The chrome driver used is 85.0.4183.87 and Chrome browser is also 85.

While executing in IE I get Unsupported Command Exception in the cucumber project.

In simple maven project all steps are in one test method but in Cucumber project the steps are divided in Given When and Then. There are 14 steps(Given When and Then) and all are in one feature file.

Comment: Please add your code trials and the exact message you are getting.

Comment: exact msg is failed at step 4 selecting the dropdown and submit  org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with remote browser. It may have died.